# comma separated double

Tags: c#, .net

Where can I set style in which double is writte by ToString() method ?
I am getting for example 2,2345 while I want to have 2.2345

thanks for ay hints,

bye

Answer (score 2):

The [`Double.ToString()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tostring.aspx) is overloaded, so you can call it with a couple of different signatures to get the output you want.

In this case, your culture settings are affecting the output of the `ToString()` function. To get the result that you want, you should call [`Double.ToString(IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045.aspx), passing in [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx):

```
myDouble.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This should solve your issue.

For future reference, note that another common version of `Double.ToString()` is the [`Double.ToString(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx) overload. The `String` parameter is a numeric format string, either one that is predefined or one that you specify. For example:

```
myDouble.ToString("format string here");
```

MSDN has a couple of articles on format strings: [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

Comment: You will not be able to change the decimal separator by only using a format string - you need to force a culture to do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
double a = 2.2345;
string b = a.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a FormatProvider, ususally as a CultureInfo.

For example:

```
string s = d1.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would want the affect to be on your whole application. This could be set on initialization. Thus, note that this would mean an effective change on *ALL* cultures.

```
var culture = new CultureInfo(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
```

Then just:

```
string value = (1002.300).ToString();
```